# Lazarus SaveToFile not working

Tags: list, dialog, save, lazarus

I've been writing code for a game and I've stumbled upon a problem when implementing saving option. I've been keeping all moves in TStringList and after a button click wanted to save that list chosen by user, but I keep getting error

"Unable to create file "C:\User\Admin\etc..."" and I can't quite find the reason for this. Here is some of my code :

```
procedure THistory.setName(name : String);
begin
  fileName := name;
end;

procedure THistory.save();
begin
  movesList.SaveToFile(fileName)
end

procedure TGameForm.saveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if saveDialog.Execute then begin
     history.setName(saveDialog.FileName);
     history.save();
  end;
end;
```

Any help would be welcome.

Im running Windows 7 64 bit, the message is as follows : Project Piłka raise exception class 'EFCreateError' with message: Unable to create file "C:\User\Admin\Desktop\Piłka\save\save1.sav"

Comment: Well, that etc. is important for us. What is the exact error message that you got ? Was that caused e.g. by access denied reason ? On which OS did you run your application ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have Unicode values in your path for that user directory. If so you might need to use the various utf8 functions in lasutf8utils library for Windows applications. Linux is not affected. Try saving to a regular ascii path first  like c:\temp and see if it works. If it does that will be the cause. So then try utf8toutf16(path)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried run program as administrator? 
In project options → Excution level try set to require Administrator.
To run program in lazarus, reopen lazarus as Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is then "ł" the "Piłka", change the path to only ansi chars or use UTF8toSys() of FileUtil